# Using ASPX View Engine with MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Is it possible to use ASPX view engine with MVC 5?

We have a product using MVC 4 on ASPX view engine and we want to migrate to MVC 5, however, when I create a new project in VS 2013, select MVC and try to add a new View, I don't see any option to add a view using ASPX View Engine. Has Microsoft stopped with ASPX View Engine? Is there any way to still use ASPX?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is what a blog post regarding the release of VS2013 said: "The HTML editor used by Razor files (.cshtml and .vbhtml) as well as normal HTML files has been replaced with entirely new code. **Web Forms (.aspx and .ascx) involve significantly more complexity and did not fit into a well-polished release for Visual Studio 2013, so they will be updated in an upcoming product release.** " Source:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/27/html-editing-features-in-visual-studio-2013-preview.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It's installed by default. just check out the `ViewEngines.Engines` collection. Its output are:

- System.Web.Mvc.WebFormViewEngine
- System.Web.Mvc.RazorViewEngine

Comment: Is there something that needs to be done to enable it, then? I've got VS 2013 Update 2 and I'm not seeing aspx as an option when creating new views. Just Razor.