# Disable *ALL* Automatic HTML Escaping in ASP.Net/Core MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, escaping

In ASP.Net/Core MVC, the auto-HTML escaping happens when you echo a string variable inside a Razor view. For example:

```
<div>@("<b>Hello</b>")</div>
```

is output as

> <div>&lt;b&gt;Hello&lt;/b&gt;</div>

How can I disable this feature by default in ASP.Net/Core MVC, **without** having to use a helper everywhere like Html.Raw(), WriteLiteral(), new HtmlString(), et cetera?

I understand the reasoning behind this functionality but I am experimenting with alternate escape methods.

Comment: There's a reason it exists, you can't turn it off.

Comment: If you don't want what Razor does, you might want to [not use Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33914625/11683).

Comment: I think you can do it by replacing the service `System.Text.Encodings.Web.HtmlEncoder` in the services collection by a fake one. It is injected [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Razor/src/RazorPageBase.cs#L96). But it can have some side effects as it can be used elsewhere in aspnet framwork

Comment: what is wrong with helper methods?

Comment: @ibubi because if you enable HTML escaping for all data coming from your database, it negates the need for Razor to escape it everywhere. Now you have to remember to use the helper method at every single place you echo a variable, or else Razor will double-escape it.

Answer (score 1):

You can not disable it.

ASP.Net/Core MVC design for preventing `Injection` (Web Application Security), the @ use frequently so it need prevent `HTML` or `Javascript` injection.