# MVC 5 View Engines

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, viewengine

I have recently started learning MVC5 (using Visual Studio 2015 Community), so I have a question about view engines.

Could someone pleased explain a bit about MVC5 view engines? I'm little bit confused, because if I, say, rename my Index.cshtml view file, I get an error message that suggests that ASPX view is being searched for first, while when I create a view, I don't have an option to choose a view engine (have to stick with Razor).

Even if I install additional templates (for example - Spark), I still don't have them offered when I try to create new view. From what I see, in MVC4 there was an option to choose from a drop down list.

I've read an article on stack overflow: [Using ASPX View Engine with MVC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696842/using-aspx-view-engine-with-mvc-5), but I'm buffed up why is it searching for ASPX first, if I can't even choose it. Any elaboration on this matter is welcome.

```
The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/ControllerName/Index.aspx
~/Views/ControllerName/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/ControllerName/Index.cshtml
~/Views/ControllerName/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
ControllerName\Index.spark
Shared\Index.spark
ControllerName\Index.shade
Shared\Index.shade
```

Comment: Its just the default. You can override it by specifying only the view engines you want in `Application_Start()` (in `Global.asax.cs`) - e.g. `ViewEngines.Engines.Clear(); ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());`

Comment: @StephenMuecke - using your suggestion, I've added the following in the `Global.asax.cs`: 
`ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();`
`ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new Spark.SparkViewEngine);`
`ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());`

After rebuilding the solution, when I  try to add a View to some controller, I still don't have the option to choose my view engine. Also, I don't even see ASPX view engine in the list when I type `ViewEngines.Engines.Add`

Any further help would be very appreciated.